# Why The Site Server IP Address Does Not Indicate City or Province

Tags: ip-address

I have a `VPS` account for my website. I chose ip location in `US`. But after I search, I do not see any cities or provinces found, so only the `US` country code.

As for other ip servers, sometimes I see a very complete address.

So I wondered. Is there any difference from ip address?
I mean, do some site servers intentionally add a `province or city` to their ip address, or does it happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

How are you searching?  There are a number of different IP geolocation databases and they all get their information in different ways.  Location information is not "attached" to the IP.

Some information, like the country, is more easily obtainable.  The IANA allocates addresses to regional authorities (e.g. ARIN) which may maintain public databases.  So you might be able to query ARIN for an IP address and, if it shows up, determine the country that ARIN allocated the address to.

More fine grained information (e.g. city, province, zip) is collected via a variety of other mechanisms.  The geolocation database owner may pay an ISP to tell them where they've allocated addresses.  They may mine web traffic and use heuristics to try and guess this information.  Each database will have different mechanisms and the accuracy of each will vary.

Comment: Means in general, ip address tracker displays only State? and will display the city and region if they work with the ISP?

Comment: It will depend on the tracker.